# Prove $n < 2^n$ using induction

Tags: inequality, induction

Newbie asking, sorry if it's something obvious.

I need to prove the following statement using induction:

$$n < 2^n$$

Starting with $n = 1$ the statement obviously is true: $1 < 2^1$

Now I have difficulties in proving that $n+1 < 2^{n+1}$. What I got so far is the following:
$$n+1 < 2^n \cdot 2$$
Then using the induction hypothesis.
$$n +1 < n\cdot 2$$
That's where I am stuck. How can I go on so this actually leads to a proof?

Comment: You are "affirming the consequent" - asserting $n+1<2^{n+1}$ when you need to prove it $\ddot\frown$

Comment: try by doing: $n<2^n\Rightarrow 2n<2^{n+1}$ and check what $2n$ and $n+1$ has as a reation for $n>1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $n<2^n$,$$n+1<2^n+1\leqslant2^n+2^n=2\times2^n=2^{n+1}.$$

Answer (score 0):

A way without induction if you wish:
$$2^n=(1+1)^n\geq1+n\cdot1=n+1.$$